# mySQL Query next id with parameters

Tags: php, sql, mysql

```
/id/desription/status/
--------------------
/1/testing01/   1  /
/2/testing02/   0  /
/3/testing03/   1  /
/4/testing04/   1  /
```

Hi,

I need to query next id where status = 1

If mySQL Query, I need query id next to id = 1 where status = 1

```
SELECT * WHERE id = (1 + 1) AND status = 1 ?
```

So my outcome is id number 3.

Thanks for the help,
appreciate lots.

Comment: WHERE id > 1 ... then you can order your result by id ASC or `SELECT MIN(id)`

Comment: Why #3? I.e. from your sample it's not obvious which row should be treated as 'row with status=1'. First? Last? Or which?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about order and limit?

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE status = 1 AND id > 1 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;
```

You should look into setting the indexes correctly here also, to ensure top performance.